# Express Gateway - Authorization

Tags: node.js, authorization, token, express-gateway

I have a simple structure as shown in the image below that I have a gateway that manage all request, validate the token, add the loggedUser in the request, and repass it to the correct container. I have a question when the containers make requests with each other because the loggedUser exists only in the first container that received the request, he doesn't repass this property to the other containers.

I have tried creating interceptors in each container in order to add the loggdUser in all requests. But it is causing hard work and I believe it can be an anti-pattern.

Also, something very supernatural happens in some requests, it is keeping the last loggedUser value of the last request made. That is a user who in fact is not actually logged in at the moment. I've done some research and haven't found much material on this. Can you tell me the best approach for this scenario.

[image]

Router

```
  router.get('/load/account', expressRouterAdapter(loadAccountControllerFactory()))
```

expressRouterAdapter

```
export const expressRouterAdapter = (controller: Controller): any => {
  return async (req: Request & { loggedUser: any}, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { body, params, headers, query } = req
    const interceptor = InterceptorAdapter.interceptRequest()
    interceptor.addHeader({Authorization: headers.authorization})
    const response = await controller.handle({ body, params, 
    headers, query })
    res.status(response.statusCode)
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    res.json(response.body)
    } else {
      res.json({
        error: response.body
      })
   }

}
```

}

Interceptor:

```
export class InterceptorAdapter implements AddRequestHeader {
  static request: AxiosInterceptorManager<AxiosRequestConfig>

  private constructor(
    expressRequest?: AxiosInterceptorManager<AxiosRequestConfig>
  ) {
    InterceptorAdapter.request = expressRequest
  }
  static interceptRequest(): InterceptorAdapter {
    axios.interceptors.request.clear()
    return new InterceptorAdapter(axios.interceptors.request)
  }

  addHeader(header: AddRequestHeader.Header) {
    InterceptorAdapter.request.use(req => {
      return { ...req, headers: { ...header } }
    }, error => error)
  }
}
```

gateway policies:

```
  - cors:    
  - log: 
      action:
        message: 'auth ${req.method}'

  - jwt:
      action:
        secretOrPublicKey: 'MY KEY'
        checkCredentialExistence: false
        
  - request-transformer:
      action:
        body: 
          add:
            loggedUser: req.user
  - proxy:
      - action:
          serviceEndpoint: svcap20Service
          changeOrigin: true
```

Comment: I think your problem is with your architecture. The containers should pass the user credentials with their requests to other containers so the receiving container can validate that the user is authorized to use whatever service is requested.

Comment: At first I thought about this approach in the architecture, but I believe that each container has its own authentication layer, maybe it wasn't necessary, since I have a Gateway in front that could do this and pass it on to the front.

Comment: Why not have the containers make requests through the gateway?

Comment: For two reasons, I have some workers working internally, they don't have authentication, they need to talk directly to containers without a token, as my project is defaulting to the initial point of communication for each container, I wouldn't want to lose this pattern and add an address pointing to the gateway in some use cases and others pointing to the container, in the case of workers' use cases. And there's the question of something bizarre happening. In some requests, the last loggedUser is locked in the express gateway req,

Comment: This supernatural problem of passing on the old logUser was already resolved, the problem was happening in my interceptor, I forgot to clear the interceptor before creating the next one.